# How can I get info from 2 tables into one sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, union-all

I have these 2 tables that I need the boat and image info from to show in the same sql/loop.

Is this possible?
With inner join?

```
$info1 = mysql_query(" SELECT image1 as image, boat1 as boat FROM all_images ");
$info2 = mysql_query(" SELECT image2 as image, boat2 as boat FROM all_boats_images ");

while($b = mysql_fetch_array($????????)){
 echo $b['boat'].$b['boat'];
}
```

Comment: Two databases or two tables? Btw, using normal language might get your question answered faster.

Comment: ok, sorry it's the same database with 2 different tables

Comment: Okay, I'll give you the answer, but it's really not that hard, just look at the JOIN documentation. Can you explain what exactly you need and perhaps show the table structures? Do you need to join the results so that id from one table matches the id on the other, or you just need to output results from both tables?

Comment: So it wasn't about the join after all. You should really pay attention when writing questions (database != table, join != getting results from two tables).

Comment: Yes, if I knew the difference, but it did not. That's why I asked :)

Comment: Haha, that's fine, now you know! :)

Comment: Haha, yes .. :) .. did you se my comment below about the structure and what I want?

Comment: Yeah, yeah, and I saw you already got an answer that was pretty close. The union one is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to use an union since you commented that the tables are not related

```
SELECT image1 as image, boat1 as boat FROM all_images
union all
SELECT image2 as image, boat2 as boat FROM all_boats_images
```

Comment: very welcome. btw. look into learning sql/t-sql it is really fun.

Answer (score 1):

just append database name before your table name

i.e. if database name is db1 and table name is tb1 then

```
          SELECT * FROM db1.tb1;
```

Comment: I asked a wrong question. It is the same database with two tables

Comment: This is actually the exact same answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT all_images.image1, all_boats_images.image2 AS image FROM all_images, all_boat_images");

 while($b = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      echo $b['boat'];
    }
```

To narrow down your results, try changing the $query to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT all_images.image1, all_boats_images.image2 AS image FROM all_images, all_boat_images WHERE all_images.id = all_boats_images.id AND all_images.id = whatever_id_you_are_searching_for");
```

Comment: Thank you! It works (almost) but it gives me over 4000 echos and I only have 250 rows in the 2 db:s (together)

Comment: If that's the case, you have to be more specific with what you're selecting. Sometimes you have to add extra statements to get what you're looking for exactly. If you tell me the other columns in your db and what you're exactly looking for in your results, we can probably narrow down the 4000 results.

Comment: should I change my first ask to show my sql or should I put it in this comment box?

Comment: db prislistor
|id|kategori|bto1|rubrik|text1|other|bild|w|h|

db all_boats_images
|id|boat_id|image|width|height|sort|boat|

My sql right now
mysql_query("SELECT prislistor.bild, all_boats_images.image AS images FROM prislistor, all_boats_images");

Comment: I saw your other example but the id is never the same from all_boat_images and all_images. The tables has nothing to do with each other. I just want to list all 250 images but it lists over 4000 :)

Comment: One table conatins 232 object and the other just 18. (232*18=4176 and that's what I get :) )

Comment: join is not what you want you want an union/union all see my answer

Comment: Yeah, Gboehm has the answer you want if you want to see all 250 objects.